Excel Formula - Get list of clients for a given Rep
I want to get a list of Clients for John. If I use index match, I just get the same client. I tried using index match with UNIQUE, but just got NA and NUM errors. What formuals do I need to use to get this working correctly? I tried a few with FILTER and UNIQUE as well but those are kinda new to me.
Sample:


INDEX(MATCH()) can return at most one row (the first the row meets criteria). Please include the FILTER() formula you tried.

=FILTER(A2:A5,B2:B5="John")

If you want it as in given example, you can use =if(B2:b5="John",a2:at,"") but FILTER as suggested above is probably what you're after.
